# Why am I not able to access the REST API exposed by my service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I am trying to incorporate a few APIs into my existing spring-boot service, but I am not able to reach the APIs for some reason, when I try to access it from Postman.

Initially I thought it might be because of missing dependencies, so I added the spring-boot-started-web dependency to my build.gradle

```
classpath(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.8.RELEASE')
```

My next troubleshooting steps involved checking the annotations of my app. After checking them, I could not find any issues.

This is the annotations of my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, RibbonAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication {
      // Some code
}
```

and this is my Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class MyApplication {

       @RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.GET}, value="/myApi", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
       public ResponseEntity<String> myApiHandler() {
           return new ResponseEntity<String>("Successfully called API", HttpStatus.OK);
       }
}
```

I had also defined the port in the application.properties file as follows:

```
server.port=6069
```

When I try to hit the following API from Postman, however, I am not able to get any response from the application:

```
localhost:6069/myApi
```

this is the error I get:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6069
```

I am using Java 8, spring boot version 1.5.8 and Intellij IDE for development. Could you please let me know what I am missing? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Silly question, have you started your spring boot server?

Comment: @PradeepSimha Yup, I have. That was the first thing I checked too. Did not stop until I saw the "Tomcat started on port 6069" message.

Comment: I tried changing the `@RequestMapping` to `@GetMapping`, however I am getting a different error now: ```Error: write EPROTO 65166088:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@GetMapping("/myApi")
```

instead of

```
@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.GET}, value="/myApi", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

This must resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried this, but now get a different error ```Error: write EPROTO 65166088:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:```

Comment: This type of issue comes when you use https instead of http. Change the URL to use http instead of https.
Example: https://localhost:6069/myApi

Change it to: http://localhost:6069/myApi

Comment: Got it! This worked. Thanks! Although I do not understand why it was not working for @RequestMapping

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, you can use @RequestMapping("/anything") at the top of your controller class and will work too you just have to change URL to localhost:6069/anything/myApi . Please upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in @RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.GET}, value="/myApi", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

you should use @GetMapping.

RequestMapping just for basic config on class level for inherited behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it did not work. I do not see reason why @RequestMapping should not work when ```@GetMapping``` would work in any case, as I am specifying the method anyway